# С++ Отсортировать список интервалов по возрастанию

Tags: c++, qt

Привет всем. Есть такая вложенность структур:

```
typedef struct
{
// текущий интервал
   QDateTime start;
   QDateTime end;
} sTimeInterval;

typedef struct
{
   QList<sTimeInterval> intervals; // множество интервалов
} sVariant;

typedef struct
{
   QList<sVariant> variants; // множество вариантов
} sSubZone;

typedef struct
{
   QList<sSubZone> subZones; // множество подзон
} sZone;
```

**Вопрос:** Что нужно сделать, что бы отсортировать **QList< sTimeInterval > intervals** в экземпляре структуры sZone по возрастанию. Нужно что то наподобие: **qSort(variants.intervals.begin(), variant.intervals.end());** Что бы каждый интервал в **sVariant** был отсортирован по возрастанию. Как такое сделать?

Comment: Можете привести пример данных в intervals с тем что есть и что должно получить? Вообще, идеально было бы это совместить с заполненным кодом, который можно было сразу запустить и с ним же играться

Comment: Предположим, что у нас есть один заполненный variants в который входит множество интервалов, пусть будет штук 200. Они располагаются там беспорядочтно. Пример 1-я итерация по интервалам start = 21.06.2017 17:13:54,  end = 21.06.2017 17:20:21, 2-я итерация по интервалам  start 21.06.2017 18:13:54  end 21.06.2017 18:17:54  Так как дата старта 2-й итерации позже даты старта 1-й итерации  их нужно поменять местами эти интервалы. Так что бы интервал 2-й итерации стоял уже на 1-й и тд и так всех 200 раз проходим

Comment: Интересно, а интервалы могут пересекаться? Если нет, достаточно по `start` отсортировать

Comment: Да по start, вот только как это сделать?

Comment: Как будет выглядеть код который это делает

Answer (score 0):

Написал функцию, которая при сортировки применялась к каждому элементу списка, которая и позволила штатными средствами отсортировать пользовательский класс:

```
#include <QDateTime>
#include <QDebug>

struct sTimeInterval
{
// текущий интервал
    QDateTime start;
    QDateTime end;

    // Example: start = 21.06.2020 17:13
    //          end = 21.06.2021 17:16
    sTimeInterval(QString start, QString end) {
        this->start = QDateTime::fromString(start, Qt::SystemLocaleShortDate);
        this->end = QDateTime::fromString(end, Qt::SystemLocaleShortDate);
    }
};


bool sortByTimeInterval(const sTimeInterval &ti1, const sTimeInterval &ti2)
{
    return ti1.start < ti2.start;
}

QDebug operator<<(QDebug debug, const sTimeInterval &timeInterval)
{
    QDebugStateSaver saver(debug);
    debug.nospace() << '<'
                    << timeInterval.start.toString(Qt::SystemLocaleShortDate)
                    << " - "
                    << timeInterval.end.toString(Qt::SystemLocaleShortDate)
                    << '>';

    return debug;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QList<sTimeInterval> intervals;
    intervals << sTimeInterval("21.06.2020 17:13", "21.06.2021 17:16")
              << sTimeInterval("21.06.2020 17:13", "21.06.2021 17:16")
              << sTimeInterval("21.06.2017 17:13", "21.06.2017 17:16")
              << sTimeInterval("21.06.2020 17:13", "21.07.2020 17:16")
              << sTimeInterval("21.06.2017 18:13", "21.06.2017 19:16");

    qDebug() << intervals;

    qSort(intervals.begin(), intervals.end(), sortByTimeInterval);

    qDebug() << intervals;

    return 0;
}
```

В консоли до сортировки:

```
(<"21.06.2020 17:13" - "21.06.2021 17:16">, <"21.06.2020 17:13" - "21.06.2021 17:16">, <"21.06.2017 17:13" - "21.06.2017 17:16">, <"21.06.2020 17:13" - "21.07.2020 17:16">, <"21.06.2017 18:13" - "21.06.2017 19:16">)
```

после:

```
(<"21.06.2017 17:13" - "21.06.2017 17:16">, <"21.06.2017 18:13" - "21.06.2017 19:16">, <"21.06.2020 17:13" - "21.06.2021 17:16">, <"21.06.2020 17:13" - "21.07.2020 17:16">, <"21.06.2020 17:13" - "21.06.2021 17:16">)
```